# Fortran language tag use

Tags: discussion, tags

Fortran is an evolving language.  On Stack Overflow we have [fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) as well as many language-revision-specific tags: [fortran77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran77); [fortran90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran90); [fortran95](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran95); [fortran2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran2003).  An idea for a [fortran2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran2008) was [not well received](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260924/3157076).

Many questions tagged as Fortran 77 [genuinely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10481109/3157076) are [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21666917/3157076) to that revision: there's an awful lot of old code out there which even young people need to understand.

Other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23794681/3157076) are tagged Fortran 77 seemingly because they use old-style features.  One can even [find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22744193/3157076) multiple revision-specific tags where it doesn't seem meaningful.

Then one has questions tagged as Fortran 77 but where the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23121572/3157076) is [merely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23941526/3157076) with the use of fixed-form source code (similar to above).  Some questions using fixed-form source use features not introduced until after Fortran 77.

Those tagged Fortran 90 and above are often: "I know it's not Fortran 77".  Very few people with free-form source code will have to care about restricting to one language revision.  It makes much more sense, if it's a "how do I do this", or "why isn't this working" to mention the compiler (including version) in the question than using a Fortran 90 or 2003 tag.

Suggestions, then:

- We remove revision-specific tags from questions where they *clearly* aren't necessary;
- We create a [fortran-fixed-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-fixed-form) (or better):

  - add this new tag to questions as necessary;
  - remove Fortran 77 tag from these questions, except where that is still sensible.
- We update tag wikis to discourage revision-specific tags except where it would be good.

I can see problems with these.  Certainly, many people who have problems because their broken fixed-form source doesn't compile (or are using the wrong file extension) wouldn't know to use a specific tag.  Further, students, say, having a supervisor dump "lots of old FORTRAN code" on them would still struggle.

Any comments on the suggestions, or how to resolve the problems even I see?

Comment: Oh yes, I can see a good use of a Fortran 77 tag even for code which merely uses old-style (personally deprecated) features: it keeps much of the "seriously, it's 2014 dude" out of the way.

Comment: The problem you illustrate isn't new, it's a problem experienced in many tags with specific revisions. The answer is not to eliminate tags or try to enforce things, instead you should simply retag (or suggest a tag edit) where applicable. Once finished, tags that are no longer used will be automatically culled.

Comment: Good points, thanks, @slugster.  I don't want to eliminate whole tags - I think each has some value - but my main concerns are: the conflation of Fortran 77 with fixed-form source; the use of Fortran 90+ as a "not Fortran 77".  Fortran is somewhat different, perhaps, even if the issues are't unique, from many other languages because of the first and the massive difference between 77 and 90.  I suppose the main purpose of the question is to see whether other people are as bothered about this as I am.

Comment: There are less than 4000 Fortran questions asked in the past 5 years, fragmenting the tag does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: ... stop using fortran?

Comment: Too many questions, these tags can be made tag-synonyms

Comment: @Will: we were using Fortran long before most other computer languages were more than a twinkle in their progenitor's eye, and our descendants will be using Fortran long after most of today's programming languages are smears on the road of history.  In 100 years your grandchildren will be writing *stop using Fortran* in comments on Stack Overflow. All together now: *That old man Fortran ... he jus' keeps rollin'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR:** Please delete the version tags for Fortran, it is too small tag itself to make those versions worth it. Or make a tool that reminds people  to use the generic tag.

I personally must say that I see this as a big problem. Just in August, which has not ended yet I retagged more than 20 questions which had only the `fortran77`,  `fortran90` or `fortran95` tag. People using the `fortran2003` don't appear to forget the generic tag though.

It is really a big mess.

People say, yes there is no problem just retag the questions, but first, you have to see them. This means you have to go through those tags from time to time and look for those questions. If you make a search with more tags it searches for an intersection, not for an union of those tags. Also many people don't have the instant edit the privilege or the edit the tags directly privilege (I too don't have that long), because it is pretty hard to get to that reputation just from Fortran.

**It is a problem even for the questioners themselves**, because often they are new here and do not know the system well. There is much smaller audience on those version tags.There are 717 followers of `fortran`, but only 212 followers of `fortran90` and only 89 followers of `fortran 77`. Fortran 95, the actually most commonly used revision has only 98 followers.

As you say, many of the tags are even applied wrong. Regarding the Fortran 90, many people would call Fortran 90 anything which is not Fortran 90 even though most of the code is actually Fortran 95 and the compilers don't even have an option to enforce Fortran 90, they only know Fortran 95. I believe it is because the unfortunate `.f90` suffix. To many people thing that it denotes the standard version. Too mane people think they should use suffixes like `.f95`, `.f03`, Alas even the well renowned FFTW3 library ships a `.f03` file!

Also I can confirm your observation of `fortran77` meaning for most people the fixed format.

It is almost as if it actually wasn't one language called Fortran but many separate languages for many people, because they automatically add the version when speaking about it. They say I am using Fortran 90, C and C++. Why not C99 and C++03?

Myself, I would really like to see an automatic tool that reminds people to use the generic tag too or even enforces it. There other way would be to delete the version tags.

On the other I do not like the idea of fixed format and free format tags. Most of the questions do not depend on the source format and often you can't even tell from the code snippets which format they use.

For now the only solutions that really works for me is to use the search query `[fortran] or [fortran77] or [fortran90] or [fortran95]` which I now found and update the RSS feeds to this one. The necessary work with retagging tens of questions still remains :(

Comment: I agree with VladimirF, one tag to rule them all.  And a loud NO to the idea of tags for fixed-format and free-format code.

Comment: I see value in [tag:fortran77] because it is a quite different problem, and I can imagine that many people would want to avoid questions around the historic intricacies.  But then, only 255 questions are so tagged.  I'll take care, though, to add [tag:fortran] there where I see it missing.  Tags for Fortran 90+ much easier to agree on.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I certainly agree with no [tag:free-format], but I still like [tag:fortran-fixed-format].  However, as in my question, it's not a tag I'd expect to be first choice; but if its mere presence, and retrospective tagging, reduces the number of "dude - column 7" answers (rather, questions needing that answer), that must be good?  Agreeing with VladimirF, fixed-form is (very) rarely the single problem, so the tag used appropriately would be infrequent.  That's an argument against, but if that isn't the source of your "loud NO" I would be interested to hear it.