# Validate against C++11 tag without C++ tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

There's been a sudden spate lately of people tagging questions with [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) but not [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

It's kind of annoying. Can we have some sort of reminder or validation pop up for this case?

*Or* if we're deciding that we [no longer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274921/560648) want [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) questions also tagged with the language tag [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), shall we generate consensus on that now? Personally I want to see the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag kept (it is not synonymous with [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03)), but I appreciate that some may find it redundant and to take up one of the five tag slots unnecessarily.

Comment: Automatically adding `c++` to anything tagged `c++98` - `c++17`+ (`c++/CLI` is arguable) seems much easier than getting consensus and teaching everyone about it. In the meantime you can use `c++*` (which unfortunately matches `c++/CLI`) in your search query or preferred tags. Same goes for `java` but probably not `python`.

Comment: We have this problem with [tag:fortran] and [tag:fortran90] for years. I retagged tens of them. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261912/fortran-language-tag-use

Comment: Sometimes I feel like I add this in 10 questions/day...

Comment: What about the tag count limit? A question can't have more than 5 tags. What if `c++` just doesn't fit? In this case it seems more important to keep `c++11` than `c++`. Just a counter-argument...

Comment: @becko: I already addressed that in the question.

Comment: Guys I'm not messing around this is _really_ pissing me off now

Answer (score 17):

In my opinion a C++ questions should always be tagged as [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and the [c++xx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bxx) should only be used to convey that they are limited to that standard.  Unfortunately I feel that if we just did a popup that some people would go okay and add [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) while others would go okay but I only want [c++xx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bxx) people so I am not going to add [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

If we forced it to have [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) then we don't have to worry about it not happening and the question should get in front of the majority of the C++ answers on Stackoverflow.  I feel that this option would be the way to handle it.

Comment: The problem is that tagging is supposed to be *flat*, aka "every tag should stand on its own, without the need of other tags".

Comment: @Braiam: That is true. Alas in practice that just doesn't work, really. I agree with Nathan in the main.

Comment: @Braiam That is true but the goal of SO is to get answers.  limiting the view of a question to subsection of answers seems to go against that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's the problem, you are expecting something the system is not capable of doing and there isn't any good reason to restructure the system to support it (the several declined FR asking for hiertachy, contains some of them). Tags are supposed to be *flat*, and the system is built on that assumtion. If you want visibility, just bite the bullet with the current tag naming scheme, and follow all the tags that interest you, or change the scheme.

Comment: @Braiam: The system is perfectly "capable" of doing this. e.g. you can't tag both [meta-tag:feature-request] and [meta-tag:bug] on meta. All I want is a little notice to pop up when tagging [tag:c++11] or [tag:c++14] but not [tag:c++]. It's not that big a deal!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What... you can perfectly tag a question on meta with any of the obligatory tags, as you see I could do on your own question, but that's beyond the point. You want a if tag = X then +Y, which is not something the system is capable to do, right now.

Comment: @Braiam If that was true, we would have to nuke 99% of all tags...

Comment: @Lundin what is not true?

Comment: @Braiam If every tag must be able to stand on its own, we would have to nuke 99% of all tags.

Comment: @Lundin I'm still not following you, what is "If that was true"?

Answer (score 6):

For C++11, just as for any of the other similar tags (C++03, C99, C11 etc), there is a tag usage clarification in the tag wiki. The C++11 tag wiki clearly states:

> Please tag questions about C++11 with the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, along with
>   the [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) tag.

There's a consensus among all SO users that this is how you tag C++ (and C) questions, period. And if you want maximum attention to your question (why wouldn't you?), you better do just that, because people will have the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) as their favourite when searching the site, not [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

If someone isn't aware of this, simply edit the post and add the correct tag.

Comment: That's what I've been doing; it's just that I've run into ten or twelve instance of this over the past few days and it's getting annoying :P I guess I'm concerned that there's some reason the pattern is on the rise and thus it'll only get worse. I'd like that we continued editing them, of course, but in practice life is short and I'd rather there were a way to "fix" the problem at source rather than spending the rest of it editing.

Comment: "because people will have the c++ as their favourite when searching the site, not c++11." that's preciselly what needs fixing. If you are interested in answering c++11 questions, why aren't you *following* the c++11 tag? You are supposed to follow the tags that would be applied to questions you are interested to answer.

Comment: @Braiam *"If you are interested in answering c++11 questions, why aren't you following the c++11 tag?"*. I see you've answered a few Python, JavaScript, and jQuery questions. I assume, then, that you're following python-2, python-2.1, python-2.2, python-2.3, python-2.4, python-2.5, python-2.6, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-3.1, python-3.2, python-3.3, python-3.4, ecmascript-3, ecmascript-4, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-7, jquery-1.3, jquery-1.3.2, jquery-1.4, jquery-1.5, jquery-1.6, jquery-1.7, jquery-1.9, jquery-1.10, and jquery-2.0? If not, why expect this of C++ folks?

Comment: @MarkAmery no, I'm not following them because I don't want to allow that brainfarted idea that each version of each language have a tag, TYVM. On this topic, the C++ standards is not the same as a those piece of software, anyways. Is like meta.SO and SO. If you want to ask about programming you ask on SO, if you want to ask about 'the site where you can ask about programming' you ask on meta.SO. Is factually simple, actually. If you want to ask about the standard itself, tag your question with the standard you want to ask about; if is generic programming, [c++] is the way to go.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My guess is that it is _that_ time of the year: when all schools start and the crap tide hits SO. It would be interesting to know if those who mis-tag their questions are mainly new users, or people with lot of previous activity in the C++ tag, and therefore should know better.

Comment: @Braiam It is assumed that if the poster isn't specifying a specific version of the standard, they are interested in the current version of it, as listed by ISO. So to be picky, questions tagged with just C++ are free to address C++11 related issues without even using the C++11 tag.

Comment: @Lundin: The questions in question aren't bad; I don't think it's that. Besides, most "start of school" questions have nothing to do with anything so "modern" as C++11 (we get C++98 _if we're lucky_!) :P

Comment: @Lundin: You mean C++14. (And I agree - unclarified, the latest standard should be assumed.)

Comment: @Lundin well, then why are you so eager of having tags for each of them?

Comment: @Braiam Because when discussing older and not yet released versions of the standard, it is good to clarify that you are only interested in that specific version. Both C++ and C have radical differences between different standard versions.

Comment: @Lundin and what's the problem with just doing that? Why you feel the need to add the c++ tag?

Comment: @Braiam Because very few will favourite "ancient junk version" or "super-early draft version" of the programming language. To reach as many as possible, the core language tag should be there. Take yours sincerely as one example. As a C programmer, I'm perfectly able to answer questions about either C90, C99 or C11. But I would never go "Hmm, lets see which C90 questions that were posted today", I don't browse the SO in that way, and I doubt others do either. I'm interested in C, period.

Comment: @Lundin exactly, that's why you shouldn't get that crap when you are browsing just C...