# How would you tag this question?

Tags: discussion

Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32422367/2069064) question, currently tagged [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)[inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inheritance)[constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constructor)[multiple-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-inheritance)[variadic-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-templates). All the tags are relevant, but somehow incomplete. In particular, I think the question is missing two important tags: [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (as per [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302729/2069064) and others) and [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates) (as it's a more popular tag than some of the others, and clearly relevant).

Question is: *should* any of the tags be replaced? If yes, which ones, and to what?

Comment: inheritance and multiple-inheritance look quite redundant.